# How to get ODBC connection by name?

Tags: .net, database, .net-3.5, odbc

Given a User DSN how do I create an ODBC connection to that data source in .Net 3.5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here is a tutorial](http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/csharp/ado-net-odbc.html) describing the entire process.

Basically, you do:

```
OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection("DSN=MyDataSourceName");
```

Comment: Depending on the driver more parameters may be needed in the connection string

Comment: Yes, but the concept works.  If the User DSN is completely configured, though, this will often be enough.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks Reed. I'll give it a try here in a bit but I'm confident it will work. Thank you for the quick response.