# Why does this OdbcConnection throw me a System.InvalidOperationException?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I am building a Winforms C# 2.0 application.

I have successfully been able to connect to my SLQ Server database using the following:
m_connexion = new SqlConnection("server=192.168.xxx.xxx;uid=...;pwd=...;database=...");

Because my company wanted to be able to use any database, I went on to use the Odbc driver and my commands went on like this:

m_connexion = new OdbcConnection("server=192.168.xxx.xxx;uid=...;pwd=...;database=...");

However, this throws out a System.InvalidOperationException. Any idea why?

I'm also trying to use a DSN, but the commend 
OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection("DSN=MyDataSourceName"); suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754302/how-to-get-odbc-connection-by-name) but it likewise throws my a System.InvalidOperationException

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The connection string needs a Provider= so that the ODBC drivers know which server you're connecting to. In this case Provider=SQLSERVER I believe.

**UPDATE:** Should have been Provider=SQLOLEDB

Comment: That did part of the trick! It now works if I provide the DSN name and uid and pwd. Any way that I can get rid of the uid and pwd? the objective was to take those out of the app

Comment: You can add ;Integrated Security=SSPI; to the connection string to use Windows authentication, instead of username/password.

Comment: Well you don't want to store the connection string in the app in the first place. Rather you'll use the <connectionStrings /> configuration element in the application's .config file and use the built in encryption provided in .NET to protect it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to specify a driver. Look here for details: http://connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005#21

Comment: I have tried Driver={SQL Native Client} but I obtain the same result

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the MDAC? You can download it from MS: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=6c050fe3-c795-4b7d-b037-185d0506396c&displaylang=en

Comment: +1 for the best site & the MDAC mention (curious which OS the m_OLogin is using!)

Comment: I am using XP SP3. I tried re-installing MDAC but same result

Answer (score 0):

If you specify a DSN, you have to configure the DSN using the ODBC control panel.  It's called "Set up data sources (ODBC)" under Administrative Tools.  The panel also has a "test" button, which might tell you more about what's going wrong.

P.S. Being "database independent" is much more work than using ODBC connection, command and datareader.  You'd have to make sure your queries run on each target database, which you will not be able to do if you don't have a test server of each.  So if I were you, I'd code it up using SqlConnection, since you already got that working.